# Error in predict.svm method for regression?

Tags: r, svm, predict

I created an svm formula, from "e1071" package,  using the following GDP:

```
library(e1071)

set.seed(100)
x <- seq(0.1, 5, by = 0.05)
w <- runif(x, min = 5, max = 6)
y <- log(x) + w ^ 2 + rnorm(x, sd = 0.2)

dt <- as.data.frame(cbind(y,x,w))

dt_train <- dt[(1:(length(x)-1)),]

dt_test <- dt[length(x),]

model <- svm(y ~ ., data = dt_train, type = "eps-regression", kernel =
    "radial", gamma = 1, cost = 1, epsilon = 0.1)
```

In order to generate predictions out-of-sample:

```
predict(model, newdata = dt_test)
```

> 28.13943

When changing the dt_test:

```
dt_test[1,] <- 100:102
predict(model, newdata = dt_test)
```

> 31.00455

However, when changing the dt_test again we get the same answer:

```
dt_test[1,] <- c(0,78,1000)
predict(model, newdata = dt_test)
```

> 31.00455

If I change again, the answer will be the same:

```
dt_test[1,] <- rnorm(3)
predict(model, newdata = dt_test)
```

> 31.00455

This error is an obstacle when I want to make predictions for time series using svm regression.
Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL/DR:  Your test data is too far away from your training data

Take a look at the distribution of your training data compared with your test data.

```
(M = sapply(dt, mean))
        y         x         w 
31.204838  2.550000  5.517325 
(S = sapply(dt, sd))
       y        x        w 
3.131271 1.436141 0.262107 

(100:102 - M)/S
        y         x         w 
 21.97036  68.55178 368.10419 
(c(0,78,1000) - M)/S
         y          x          w 
  -9.96555   52.53664 3794.18628 
(rnorm(3) - M)/S
         y          x          w 
 -9.118284  -1.747814 -15.895867
```

Your first  data point is 368 standard deviations away from the mean.
Your second data point is 3794 standard deviations away from the mean.
Your third  data point is a mere 16 standard deviations away from the mean.
These points are essentially at infinity.

You are discovering that far from the training data, your model is predicting a constant. But if you take data points that are fewer than 3 standard deviations from your training data, you will find that the model is not constant.